# explode string with different operator

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, algorithm

This is possible to explode a string with different operator ?

I need to get every code (of differents sizes) number the `[` `]`

this is an example of all the differents possibility in enter :

```js
const codes = [
   '[5018902847][592][50189272809][5089113805]',
   '[3898]',
   '[375001833][3475001021]',
    '',
]
```

and what I need:

```js
[5018902847, 592, 50189272809, 5089113805]
[3898]
[375001833, 3475001021]
null // because code is empty
```

My first solution it's something like this :

```js
codes.map(code => {
    const res = code.split('[ '| '][' | ']');
    console.log(res)
})
```

but an example of result is :

```
[
  ' [5',
  '51889',
  '28475][5',
  '51889424192][5',
  '518892728',
  '9][5',
  '518891138',
  '5]'
]
```

Comment: _"but an example of result is..."_ - `console.log('[ '| '][' | ']')` will tell you why

Comment: Actually I don't understand why there is someting like `[5` alone for example

Comment: Just do what I've suggested in my first comment. What is the output and therefor your argument for `.split()`?

Comment: `codes.map(code => code.match(/\d+/g))`

Comment: @Andreas ok thanks, the code return 0, I did not know

Comment: @AlexeyLebedev it works perfectly, could you please explain why ? I don' t understand your regex

Comment: Depending on the codes, it might not be possible to convert them from strings to numbers. For example if the codes can start with 0, or can have more than 15 digits.

Comment: @samuel the regexp matches sequences of one or more digits. `\d` means digit, `+` means one or more, `/g` means collect all matches (as opposed to stopping after the first one)

Comment: @Andreas the max safe integer is `9007199254740991`, so `9999999999999999` also containing 16 digits is not safe. If you try evaluating it in JavaScript, it's going to round up to `10000000000000000`

Answer (score 2):

You could use [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

```js
const codes = [
  "[5018902847][592][50189272809][5089113805]",
  "[3898]",
  "[375001833][3475001021]",
  "",
]

const res = codes.map((code) => {
  const extracted = code.match(/\d+/g)
  return extracted && extracted.map(Number)
})

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a regex separator :

```
> '[5018902847][592][50189272809][5089113805]'.split(/[\[\]]/)
[
  '',
  '5018902847',
  '',
  '592',
  '',
  '50189272809',
  '',
  '5089113805',
  ''
]
```

To transform your `codes` array to the desired format, here's a cool one-liner :

```
const codes = [
   '[5018902847][592][50189272809][5089113805]',
   '[3898]',
   '[375001833][3475001021]',
    '',
]
const cleanedCodes = codes.map(code => code.split(/[\[\]]/).filter(s => s.length)).filter(a => a.length)
console.log(cleanedCodes);
/*
 * will output : [
 *  [ '5018902847', '592', '50189272809', '5089113805' ],
 *  [ '3898' ],
 *  [ '375001833', '3475001021' ]
 * ]
 *
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without `match` as well (from @hgb123 answer).

```js
const codes = [
  "[5018902847][592][50189272809][5089113805]",
  "[3898]",
  "[375001833][3475001021]",
  "",
]

const res = codes.map((code) => {
  var extracted = code.split(']').filter(Boolean).map(x => {return x.replace("[","");})
  return extracted && extracted.map(Number)
})

console.log(res)
```